# Function to make a public and shared Google document accessible and viewable only with passwords

Tags: google-apps-script

Function to make a public and shared Google document accessible and viewable only with passwords.

I have a public document on Google accessible to anyone with the link.
I need a script that forces the user to enter the password before seeing and editing the spreadsheet.
Google has the ability to share file using email, but some people do not use Gmail.
The page where the code is written starts like this.

code:

```
function myFunction() {

}
```

I do not even know the kind of language I have to use.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want one password for everyone? Do you want to embed it into a website? Do you want your own webapp? Presumably you want to do it in google-apps-script since that's the tag you've chosen. So do you know javascript. You might want to read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and [ask].

Comment: 'Do you want one password for everyone?'
Yes I do.
'Do you want to embed it into a website?'
It is non necessary.
'Do you want your own webapp?'
No I only looking for a script to get a pubblic sheet with password. The user who does not have the password can not read or write in the sheet.
'Presumably you want to do it in google-apps-script since that's the tag you've chosen.'
I don't know what I must use for my goal.
'So do you know javascript.'
Yes I know javascript but I can not write this thing.
'You might want to read this and How to Ask.'
These pages do not help me.

Comment: Well first of all Stack Overflow is not a script mill.  You need to plan on writing this yourself.  If you know Javascript then it will easier for you to learn google apps script.  Start [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Comment: You did not help me.

Comment: How can I help you?

Comment: I have read the reference but do not find a function that allows a password to access the document. I can not make the private sheet link because some recipients do not use Gmail.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/

Comment: So I would suggest a webapp in which you implement your own verification of password before you give them access to editing the spreadsheet.  You can store passwords in a spreadsheet or a database via a JDBC connection.  Which would you prefer?

Comment: I do not know how to handle a JDBC database, maybe it's simpler to have a spreadsheet. In your opinion what solution is the best?

Comment: The best answer depends upon the person writing the code.  In this case, that's you.  So it sounds like your going to store the password in a spreadsheet.

Comment: So how many people might be editing the spreadsheet at any one time?

Comment: I expect a maximum of 5 contemporary users.

Comment: That will be one of the more difficult issues to deal with you make want to take a look at the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/).

Answer (score 0):

## Editable Spreadsheet on WebApp

Here's a [link](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/html-spreadsheet) to a webapp that puts an editable spreadsheet on a webapp.

Comment: Thanks a lot, tomorrow I read your code, now I'm going to bed. Thank you very much. I did not think he needed so much code.

Comment: I've added code.gs and htmlss.html to script.google.com but when I open the link on any device the system does not ask me to enter a password.

Comment: Yes.  That's something that you will have to add.

Comment: Adding a login with a single password is a pretty simple thing to do.  It only requires one text box and one button.